# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so im kinda new in php and i was trying to do this when i got the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in .../index.php on line 44

my code :

```
if ($_SESSION['uid']){
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE id= '".$uid."'");
    if ($result->num_rows){
        session_destroy();
        echo "please <a href=\"login.php\">Login<a> to your account, or <a href=\"register.php\">Register<a> a new account! \n";
    }else{
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "Welcome back, <a href=\"index.php?act=profile&id=" .$row['id']."\">".$row['username']."</a> !\n";
    }
}
else {
    echo "please <a href=\"login.php\">Login<a> to your account, or <a href=\"register.php\">Register<a> a new account! \n";
}
```

and this is my line 44:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

i dont understand what am i doing wrong!

Comment: no result from query,try to print the query and execute manually

Comment: did you start the session? and you are using `mysqli_` to connect with, right?

Comment: plus, your query was probably successful and then you destroy the session, that's what your code translates to. You're telling it "if query is good and that num_rows found a row, destroy the session; *why?* your `else{...}` is failing because you've got things set backwards; *a bit confusing*.

Comment: `if ($result->num_rows){ $row = $result->fetch_assoc();... } else{ session_destroy(); echo "please...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backwards: You call `fetch_assoc` when there aren't any rows (`$result->num_rows` is 0). You should instead do `if ($result->num_rows === 0){`.